# CLion, SDL2, CMake: No available video device

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, sdl-2, clion

I am trying to start using SDL2 (with CLion as my IDE), but I'm running into errors. I'm on Pop!_OS 19.10 (based on ubuntu)

Here are the relevant project files:

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(sdlpractice)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(sdlpractice main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sdlpractice ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "stdio.h"

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    // The window we will be rendering to
    SDL_Window * ptrWindow = NULL;
    // The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface * ptrScreenSurface = NULL;
    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    } else {
        // Create window
        ptrWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Practice",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (ptrWindow == nullptr) {
            printf("Window creation failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
        // Get window surface
        ptrScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(ptrWindow);
        // Fill the surface white
        SDL_FillRect(ptrScreenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ptrScreenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        // Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ptrWindow);
        // Wait 2 seconds
        SDL_Delay(2000);
        // Destroy window, quit SDL subsystems
        SDL_DestroyWindow(ptrWindow);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: No available video device
```

I have tried setting DISPLAY=:0.0 in CLion's run configurations. Same error results. Futhermore, I ran

```
echo $DISPLAY 
:1
```

and tried using :1 as well, same error persists.

Comment: Can you run `DISPLAY=:1 glxgears` ? If so, can you run the compiled `sdlpractice` binary outside of CLion? If so, are you _sure_ you set your run configuration correctly?

Comment: @Botje glxgears works. running ./sdlpractice in my terminal gives the same error.

Comment: Furthermore, if I add SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11 to the environment, I get the error x11 not available.

Comment: Did you install SDL2 from source or with `apt`? If the first, how did you configure it?

Comment: I installed from source first `hg clone https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL SDL` (and built), but at some point afterwards I did install through apt for some reason as well.

Comment: It is very probable that the one you built yourself disabled crucial video modes because it was missing required headers. Remove it (`/usr/local/bin/sdl2-config`, `/usr/local/include/SDL2` and `/usr/local/lib/libSDL2*`) and try again with the version from apt.

Comment: Thank you, removed the files as instructed and it runs properly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `/usr/local/bin/sdl2-config`,`/usr/local/include/SDL2` and `/usr/local/lib/libSDL2*` (as suggested by Botje) solved the problem due to the self-built version of SDL2 missing the required video headers.