# SDL2: Could not create window: No available video device

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to use the [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) library to build a C++ program. I've installed the library from `apt`, so didn't compile it myself. I'm also using CMAKE.

The problem is that I can't run the program because it reports an error saying:

> Could not create window: No available video device

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077009/sdl2-fails-to-get-display-mode-inside-virtual-machine-no-available-video-device) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001175/clion-sdl2-cmake-no-available-video-device) and much more links, but none worked. I already installed:

- xorg-dev
- libx11-dev
- libgl1-mesa-glx
- libsdl2-dev

(with `sudo apt install xorg-dev libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libsdl2-dev`.)

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` show?

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] in your question?

Comment: @pptaszni It shows nothing...

Comment: Are you using a server or wsl?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Not, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop with X.org.

Comment: Mhmm, try to `DISPLAY=:0.0 ./yourApplication`. Or first `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and after that run your app.

Comment: @pptaszni Yeah, it works! Is it possible to tell Cmake (on VSCode) to debug this way? Because I can run on the command line, but can't debug.

Comment: Did not try it, but maybe https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/ENV.html with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set.html#command:set will work.

Comment: I recommend that you ask a specific question about setting environment variables when running from VSCode (or try to do a general search if this has been solved, here or elsewhere, before).

Comment: @pptaszni thank you! Maybe you can write a formal answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay, I'll do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `DISPLAY` [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) is not set, you can either set it inline along with your app command

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 ./yourApp
```

or set it permanently in the console where you execute your app:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
./yourApp
```

To set environmental variables from CMake, you can use [cmake set command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable) `set(ENV{DISPLAY} :0.0)`